# OFFSET effect on query in Vertica

Tags: sql, performance, vertica

In my code i should read all records of a table and i use this query in a for loop:

```
SELECT * FROM EVENT ORDER BY EV_TIMESTAMP , ID LIMIT 50000 OFFSET ...
```

and every time OFFSET value will be updated.

but i found the query time will be increase by increasing OFFSET.

[image: Chart of Query time of 1k offset vs 5M offset (100 iteration)]

### Chart of Query time of 1k offset vs 5M offset (100 iteration)

[image: Chart of Query time increment by increasing OFFSET (100 sample with 50K step, it means 0,50K,100K, ...)]

### Chart of Query time increment by increasing OFFSET (100 sample with 50K step, it means 0,50K,100K, ...)

(also I have a projection based on this query)

How can i fix the issue?

■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■

■■Update -1- based on @jarlh comment■■

I changed this query_1:

```
SELECT * FROM EVENT ORDER BY EV_TIMESTAMP , ID LIMIT 50000 OFFSET 50000000
```

to this one query_2:

```
SELECT * FROM CE_EVENT where internal_timestamp>='2018-06-09 16:55:27' and id>4311750001 ORDER BY INTERNAL_TIMESTAMP , ID LIMIT 50000
```

internal_timestamp and id should be taken from last loop.

I showed query_1 takes about 2.93 seconds, but in next image you can see query_2 (with same result) takes 0.92 seconds (for 100 iteration):

[image]
Green line is related to query_2, Blue one related to query_1

■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■

Thanks for @jarlh , his suggestion helped me.

but the my question is **why should OFFSET affect the query performance?** 
Is this a bug or misbehavior in Vertica??

Comment: Skip OFFSET, use WHERE EV_TIMESTAMP  and ID bigger than previous chunk.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks, It fixed the issue. I updated your suggestion with new result in question